# Draw curved path between two objects on a <Canvas/> in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, geometry

I am playing around with some stuff in Silverlight, and I am trying to dynamically draw a curved line between two other objects on a `<Canvas/>`. I tried doing something like this:

public partial class MainNodeConnection : UserControl
{
    private MainNode _sourceNode;
    public MainNode SourceNode 
    {
        get { return _sourceNode; }
        set { _sourceNode = value; }
    }

```
private ChildNode _targetNode;
public ChildNode TargetNode 
{
    get { return _targetNode; }
    set { _targetNode = value; }
}

private double _sourceX;
private double _sourceY;
private double _targetX;
private double _targetY;

private Path _connection;

public MainNodeConnection()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _connection = new Path();
    this.Content = _connection;
}

public void UpdateLocations()
{
    _sourceX = Canvas.GetLeft(_sourceNode) + (SourceNode.Width/2);
    _sourceY = Canvas.GetTop(_sourceNode) + (SourceNode.Height/2);
    _targetX = Canvas.GetLeft(_targetNode);
    _targetY = Canvas.GetTop(_targetNode);
    string pathData = String.Format("M {0},{1} C {2},{3} {4},{5}", _sourceX, _sourceY, _targetX - _sourceX, _targetY - _sourceX, _targetX, _targetY);
    PathGeometry geoData = new PathGeometry();
    PathFigure pFigure = new PathFigure();
    pFigure.StartPoint = new Point(_sourceX, _sourceY);
    BezierSegment pseg = new BezierSegment();
    pseg.Point1 = new Point(_targetX - _sourceX, _targetY - _sourceY);
    pFigure.Segments.Add(pseg);
    geoData.Figures.Add(pFigure);
    _connection.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    _connection.StrokeThickness = 1;
    _connection.Data = geoData;
    this.Content = _connection;
}
```

}

and I built the objects on the `<Canvas/>` like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainNodeConnection mnc = new MainNodeConnection();
        mnc.Width = 300;
        mnc.Height = 300;
        Canvas.SetLeft(mnc, Canvas.GetLeft(mainNode1));
        Canvas.SetTop(mnc, Canvas.GetTop(mainNode1));
        mnc.SourceNode = mainNode1;
        mnc.TargetNode = childNode1;
        nodeCanvas.Children.Add(mnc);
        mnc.UpdateLocations();
    }
}
```

the problem I have is I can't get the line to show up. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, or is there a different/better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `Point2` and `Point3` in the Bezier curve.
From the help file:

> A cubic Bezier curve is defined by
>   four points: a start point, an end
>   point (Point3), and two control points
>   (Point1 and Point2). The BezierSegment
>   class does not contain a property for
>   the starting point of the curve; it
>   only defines the end point. The
>   beginning point of the curve is the
>   current point of the PathFigure to
>   which the BezierSegment is added.
>
> The two control points of a cubic
>   Bezier curve behave like magnets,
>   attracting portions of what would
>   otherwise be a straight line toward
>   themselves and producing a curve. The
>   first control point, Point1, affects
>   the beginning portion of the curve;
>   the second control point, Point2,
>   affects the ending portion of the
>   curve. Note that the curve doesn't
>   necessarily pass through either of the
>   control points; each control point
>   moves its portion of the line toward
>   itself, but not through itself.

Comment: there isn't, at least not in SL. you could potentially try an `ArcSegment` though as that may be easier to just create the allusion of a curve without the points. you'll need a start, end and radius.

Comment: its ok, i got it working now. wrote a method to generate intermediate points based on start and end points.